# How to get a Standard EXE and WinService EXE to communicate with each other?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-services, uac

We have an application that is part standard EXE and part WinService EXE. The standard EXE is spawned by the Run section of the registry and comes to life at login under the credentials of the user who just logged in. The WinService EXE is set to Auto Run and therefore is always running and is running as LocalSystem (essentially administrator).

We need these two programs to share data by writing information to XML files.

The app works fine when the logged in user has access to the installed folder (C:\Program Files\ourApp). The Standard EXE writes the data and the WinService EXE reads it without issue, all is well.

However, when the logged in user does not have access to write to the installed folder, the data gets caught up in UAC Virtualization and Data Redirection and ends up somewhere else and the WinService does not find nor cannot read it from the installed folder.

To circumvent this, we tried having both the standard EXE and the WinService EXE write to and read from %ProgramData%. This would work fine except that standard users do not have permissions to write to %ProgramData%.

We cannot use %LocalAppData% because for the logged in user that would be C:\Users\LoggedInUser\AppData\Local and for the winservice it would be C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local.

Is there any place left in Vista and Win7 with UAC Virtualization enabled that will allow both a Standard EXE running with only user priveleges and a WinService running as LocalSystem to talk to each other. We tried the registry but the problems are even worse. Also last but not least. We need this to work with XP without any differences in code. Meaning XP also has environment variables for %ProgramData%, %LocalAppData% etc, can it work in both.

Comment: Whatever solution you come up with will need to cope with the possibility that two users will be logged in (and running your application) at the same time.

Comment: During installation you can edit permissions on `%ProgramData%\YourAppDirectory` to allow write access to everyone. The default permissions there: anyone can create new files and folder there, and everyone can read them, but only the creator-owner (and administrators) has write access to these files. And you can change this. Also you can change permissions in `Program Files` too but it's not recommended; additionally you should not write data into `Program Files`.

Answer (score 3):

Two ideas:

1. Have each app expose a WCF endpoint using the named pipe
   transport, and have them talk to each other over a simple interface
   of your choosing.
2. Use [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) to communicate like
   you were with disk files.

Comment: Awesome.  A response so quickly, thanks!  I'm actually asking this question for a co-worker (he didn't have a stackoverflow account, so he typed up a quick email and had me post it here).  On Monday he'll be trying your suggestions (and any others).  So thanks, and hopefully I'll be applying a green check-mark for your answer!  I'll upvote, now, for the effort.

Comment: @JustLooking: If it isn't convenient to eliminate the disk files, I'd suggest using the user's local application data directory (or rather, a subdirectory) and using named pipes (or a similar IPC method) to send the directory path from the application to the service.